# Problema con tablas de FreeStyleGrids en Genexus Ev3U5

Tags: genexus

En este upgrade no estoy encontrando la forma de trabajar la tabla dentro de la free style grid para que sea responsive...

Le estoy errando en algo o no me está dando corte al seteo?

Adjunto video de lo que hago: [FreeStyleGrid Resonsive](https://youtu.be/wp2UbWxmTUw)

Nota: Ante algunas respuestas, el botón derecho sobre la grilla no muestra un menú contextual.

Por las dudas, les dejo una imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, por favor redacta tu pregunta de tal forma que si el video deja de existir la pregunta siga siendo comprensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta desde la Document Outliner tool window.

Busca el Freestyle Grid y hace clic derecho sobre la tabla que está dentro del Freestyle Grid. Si la tabla no es Responsive, ahí aparecerá la opción `Convert to Responsive Table`.

Luego de que la conviertas a Responsive, aparecerá la opción `Responsive Sizes`.

Para habilitarla ve a `View -> Other Tool Windows -> Document Outliner`.

Igualmente, creo que se debería poder hacer como tu lo estás intentando, y que habría que corregirlo.

Comment: Con esta opción, me muestra el menú contextual en la grilla pero no aparece la opción responsive sizes.

Comment: Tenes que hacer clic derecho sobre la tabla que está dentro del Freestyle Grid. Ahí aparece la opción "Convert to Responsive Table". Luego de que la conviertas, aparecerá la opción Responsive Sizes. Actualizo mi respuesta con esto.

Comment: Fue medio complicado en esta versión pero pude encontrar  el "Convert". Lo otro es que no me está funcionando el menú contextual en las tablas que están apareciendo ahora arriba de la MainTable

Answer (score 0):

Si seleccionas el Grid en el Layout, y luego haces botón derecho sobre el Grid en la parte superior de la pantalla, ahí deberías tener la opción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Marcos, como va? No me da corte el botón derecho sobre la grilla...